# Creating interactive ajax javascript widgets in ruby / rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, widget

Looking to create interactive javascript widget using ruby-on-rails that can be placed on any website.

I am able to create a basic widget. Its fairly straightforward (eg. using document.write)  This works fine for taking data from my server and putting it into the widget but its very static.

But how do I create something more dynamic / interactive / ajaxy?

I want to be able to do ajax calls using link_to_remote or something and be able to pull data from my server and update the widget as a user interacts with it.

Any ideas? If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since your goal is a widget that can be used from any website, you can't use "Ajax" due to the [Same origin security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) policy.

What you can do is create an interactive widget that uses the [JSONP pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) to fetch data from any server.

Using JSONP, your widget can interact with your website even though it is a part of some other webpage that has nothing to do with your website.

There are libraries for using JSONP easily from within your Javascript program. They include:

- [YUI JSONP](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/jsonp/) library from Yahoo
- [JQuery support](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29)

And others. In any case, you can certainly use Rails as your backend.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest rather than develop a new widget spec, that you take a look at the [W3C Widgets specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/) and implement that in Ruby.

There is an existing Apache project (Wookie) that has some of its code already ported to Ruby. Wookie uses a server-side proxy to avoid same origin issues for Ajax widgets.